# Update TableView without refreshing the window?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have this window with a few TextFields and a TableView. I have made a search engine which every time I write in the TextFields, will display a new array of the given objects which fit what ever I write in the TextFields. Now, I have tested it, and I know that the search engine works. But the problem comes when I try to update the TableView. I have tried to work my way through it, but the only fix I can think of, is to refresh the whole window every time I type something in one of the TextFields. But this is obviously not a good thing to do.

So my question is: Do you know how to refresh the list in the TableView, without refreshing the whole window? Or is there anything else I can use to visually display for example "Person" objects, make them click-able and holds pointers to the given objects?

Please come with any input you have, and I will be happy to either try or discuss what you have to say!

Comment: Use fireTableCellUpdated(row, col); in order to update the value of a single cell, or fireTableRowsUpdated(int firstRow, int lastRow); for one or more rows.

Comment: I am not sure is this is what I am looking for. Let's say I have an array of 1 million Person objects displayed. Then I type something else in one TextField, and my search method return an array with halv a million objects. Is there an efficient way to display this? For some reason setItems(Observablelist ol); causes problems.

Comment: The AbstractTableModel is efficient by default. Even when you have a few million rows in your ResultSet, definitely no more than 100 lines maximum can be displayed on the screen at a time. Give it a try.

Comment: @CostisAivalis Those are Swing table model methods, not JavaFX `TableView` methods.

Comment: Ah, so that's why I could't find the methods mentioned... Thanks for noticing, @James_D.

Comment: Have you tried using a [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html)? There's an example [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) (that example also sorts, which may be more than you need).

Comment: This looks very promising. I will come back to you asap with the results!

Comment: Doesn't the SampleTableModel class inherit from the AbstractTableModel class?

Comment: @CostisAivalis, that is true. I might have missed something, but I can't see where the JavaFX TableView is connected to SampleTableModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue!

setItems(); seems to call the object.equals();

I made a misstake in my @Override of the .equals();

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.birthNo.equals(((Person) obj).getBirthNo());
}
```

Corrected this to:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj != null && this.birthNo.equals(((Person) obj).getBirthNo());
}
```